# Override an array in prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, inheritance, prototype

I am working on a feature which requires inheritance as follows:

```
function parent() {}
parent.prototype.someProperty = ['common'];

var child1 = new parent();
```

I want to override some of the properties. If this was a primitive data type, it was easy but `someProperty` is an array.
Here child1 has a few other values in `someProperty` like `['common', 'common2', 'common3']`.

Now this is an array, so if I push elements like `child1.someProperty.push('common2');` they will end up in the `parent` as well by reference.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Things that I have thought of

- copy the array from the prototype and then attach it to `child1`. The problem is here that I will have to run through the whole array and then copy it. I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this.
- Have something like `function parent() { someProperty = ['common'];}`. This will give `someProperty` to all children so then any value can be easily pushed into it without disturbing other children objects.

I am inclined towards the second approach but I just want to make sure if there are better approaches out there.

Comment: The second option is generally how that's supposed to be done. You should only directly attach it to the prototype if you want it shared between all instances of the object.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

if you have properties that will change per instance they are better off living on the instance itself, not the prototype. if you have data that needs to be shared by all instances of a certain class you have two options.

1) Slap the property on the prototype like you have been doing. This works really well for functions but I almost never put data / non function references on the prototype. This is partly for style and partly for consistency.

2)Attach the property 'statically' to the constructor function and access it like `Circle.PI` instead of `cirlceInstance.PI`

In your case it seems like this array should be an instance property.

`var Thing1 = function() { this.property = []; }`

Comment: You should answer the question directly. The OP asks for a way to define a property on the parent that can be overwritten by the child. Your answer does not make this clear and makes little reference to the OP's code.